# error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::map<int, double>::iterator

Tags: c++, class, iterator, copy-constructor

```
     //a class used to make operations on Polynominal   
    class Polynominal
        {
        public:
            map<int, double> monomial;//int is exp，double is coefficient
            Polynominal();
            ~Polynominal();
            Polynominal(const Polynominal& other);
            /*...many functions*/
        };

        //copy constructor
        Polynominal::Polynominal(const Polynominal& other)
        {
            map<int, double>::iterator iter;

        /*Throw error here. If I replace it with 
           "map<int, double>tem=other.monomial;" 
           and then operate on tem, then it run well.*/
          for(iter=other.monomial.begin();iter!=other.monomial.end();iter++)
              monomial.insert(pair<int, double>(iter->first, iter->second));
        }
```

In the process of using iterator, it throws an error. If I replace it with
`map<int, double>tem=other.monomial;` and then operate on tem, then it run well. 
  I know putting data in public is a bad habit, but now I just want to know why it throw this error. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of the code posted is irrelevant. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Was `=default` too simple? `const Polynominal& other` => you need a `const_iterator`.

Comment: Easier to do `for (auto const& kv : other.monomial) monomial.insert(kv);`.  O'Neil's suggestion is even more easy.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is `other` is a const reference which making `other.monomial` const as well so only version of [`std::map::begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/begin) that returns const iterator is available, but you try to assign it to regular iterator. Fix could be of changing your iterator type:

```
  map<int, double>::const_iterator iter;
```

but you better use `auto` instead or even better for range loop:

```
 for( const auto &p : other.monomial )
          monomial.insert( p );
```

However it is not clear why you need to implement copy ctor manually at all, compiler generated will do what you need without any effort.